# Fill shape created using "Pen Tool"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, stroke, pen-tool, fill

I have created an Arc using *Pen Tool* in a new layer. I want to fill and the convert it into a shape for further manipulation.

I tried "Ctrl + left click" on layer to select the stroke as well as *invert* select, to select shape/stroke outline, nothing happened.

I'm entirely new to Photoshop CS5 and graphic design.

Your guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

> Photoshop CS5 / Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to save the shape for further manipulation, all you need to do is name the path in the **Path** window so it won't get overwritten when you create another shape.

If you don't see your **Paths** window go to **Window > Path** to show it.

To create a shape with the pen tool from the start, make sure the **Shape Layer** icon is selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can also add "right click stroke created and choose fill stroke" ;)

Comment: No problem, welcome to GD!